# Creating generic classes with generic properties

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
public class Class1<T> 
        where T : SubClass1, new()
{
    public T Item { get; protected set; }

    public Class1()
    {
        Item = new T();
    }
}

public class Class2<T> : Class1<T> 
    where T : SubClass1, new()
{
    public Class2()
    {
        Item = new T();
    }
}

public class SubClass1
{
    public string Text { get; protected set; }

    public SubClass1()
    {
        Text = "SubClass1";
    }
}

public class SubClass2 : SubClass1
{
    public SubClass2()
    {
        Text = "SubClass2";
    }
}
```

Now I want a generic method to create those classes, so I make this:

```
public T GetInstance<T, K>() 
            where T : Class1<K>, new()
            where K : SubClass1, new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

But if I call that method, I have to do this:

```
GetInstance<Class2<SubClass1>, SubClass1>();
```

So I'm specifying `SubClass1` twice to call the method. My question is, is there a neater way of doing this which would be more like this:

```
GetInstance<Class2<SubClass1>>();
```

And therefore avoid specifying `SubClass1` twice? Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Comment: something like `T<K>`?